# Overriding customer-completed-order.php doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've overridden woo-commerce *customer-completed-order.php* template in the child theme of Wordpress. Though email is not sent if the order is created.

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // optional (to test without it)

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
    $product_name = $item['name']; // product name
}
/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php printf( __( "Hi there. Your recent order on %s has been completed.", 'woocommerce' ), $product_name ); ?></p>


<?php
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, i've enabled php errors logging by adding the following lines to *wp-config.php*:

```
// log php errors
@ini_set('log_errors','On'); // enable or disable php error logging (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('display_errors','Off'); // enable or disable public display of errors (use 'On' or 'Off')
@ini_set('error_log','php-errors.log'); // path to server-writable log file
```

There was an error in php_errors.log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   get_items() on boolean

so removing line `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // optional (to test without it)`

resolved the problem